# The utility of kernel methods like RKHS in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

In machine learning framework, kernel methods are widely used to find the close-form solution of a optimization problem, which restricts the solution in an RKHS. However, it really puzzles me that whether RKHS works in practice, that is to say, whether the assumption is valid that the solution lies in an RKHS. I know one of the most classic examples to use kernel methods is support vector machine(SVM) and I recently have worked on a sampling algorithm, Stein Variational Gradient Descent(SVGD, Liu et al 2016), which also utilize RKHS to find the optimal velocity field. Considering that the functions in an RKHS is quite limited, I do think kernel methods sacrifice too much in order to obtain computation efficiency. Can any one explain whether my doubts on the assumption of RKHS is reasonable or not? Maybe it is better with some specific examples.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: [Any specific advantages/insights for kernel Ridge-regression in RKHS?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3552886/any-specific-advantages-insights-for-kernel-ridge-regression-in-rkhs?rq=1)

Comment: It depends on the kernel you are using. The Gaussian RBF kernel will allow you to approximate any continuous function, whereas low-dimensional polynomial kernels such as $K(x,y)=(x^T y)^2$ will not. I can expand on this if you want, but I am not sure what exactly it is that you are looking for

Comment: Why do you think that "the functions in an RKHS is quite limited" ? Limited in what way and compared to what? Furthermore, the space depends on your choice of kernel. If your function space is too small/inappropriate, just use a different kernel!

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you do!@ClaudioMoneo

Comment: Actually I mean an RKHS with a specific kernel consists of very limited functions. For instance, I want to consider those functions in C_{b}^{\inf}, but in order to find a close-form solution I restrict it to the RKHS with Gaussian RBF kernel. Then this RKHS may contain much fewer functions. But as Claudio mentioned, maybe it could approximate any continuous functions, and then my question is solved. I have no idea about this before. @gg

Answer (score 1):

The paper [Universal Kernels](https://jmlr.org/papers/volume7/micchelli06a/micchelli06a.pdf) investigate conditions on the features of a continuous kernel so that it may approximate an arbitrary continuous target function uniformly on any compact subset of the input space. A number of concrete examples are given.

You can find some related arxiv file searching for "[\(\mathcal{H}_K\) universal kernel](https://www.searchonmath.com/arxiv/result?q=%5C%28%5Cmathcal%7BH%7D_K%5C%29%20universal%20kernel%20&domains=x) " on SearchOnMath, for instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! This paper really helps me get much more insights about kernel methods.